# Case-insensitive searching in indexedDB

Tags: indexeddb, case-sensitive

Can someone please tell me if it is possible to execute case-insensitive search on indexeddb object store using index, openCursor and keyRange....
I can do case sensitive and managed to implement something using toUpperCase function but there are so many different varaitions that it is not feasible relly...
Any help welcomed... Thanx...
Example of an attempt:

```
var transaction = db.transaction("products", IDBTransaction.READ_ONLY);
var store = transaction.objectStore("products");
var descIndex = store.index('Index1');
var boundKeyRangeUpper = IDBKeyRange.bound(request.term.toUpperCase(), (request.term.toUpperCase()+'Z'));
descIndex.openCursor(boundKeyRangeUpper).onsuccess = function (e)
```

**UPDATE**
This is what I ended up implementing:
Four ranges that cover and possibility i.e. FA,fA,Fa,fa... This is done on the first letter only i.e. 'F'

`var boundKeyRangeUpper = IDBKeyRange.bound(term.toUpperCase(), term.toUpperCase()+'Z');
var boundKeyRangeUpper2 = IDBKeyRange.bound(term.toUpperCase(), term.toUpperCase()+'z');
var boundKeyRangeLower = IDBKeyRange.bound(term.toLowerCase(), term.toLowerCase()+'z');
var boundKeyRangeLower2 = IDBKeyRange.bound(term.toLowerCase(), term.toLowerCase()+'Z');`

The results of the searches above is stored in another objectStore but with their description as uppercase hence FISH, FRUIT, FRESH SALAD... Now if a letter is pressed after F e.g. 'r' the search will look into this new object store where everything is uppercase... This is not an ideal solution by far but it works and it is quick for my needs... Perhaps we will get case insensative search eventually, perhaps not...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend modifying the structure of the object store, this is by adding a column (i.e. a property to each object in the store) with the same value of the key BUT to upper case, then make this new property the key instead.

```
//object
var lang = {
    name: 'Javascript',
    keyName: '', //THE NEW PROPERTY - KEY OF THE OBJECTSTORE
    interest: 100
};
```

when you add an object to the store modify the new property with the uppercase of the name (or term or whatever) so the object will be:

```
//object
var lang = {
    name: 'Javascript',
    keyName: 'JAVASCRIPT', // NEW PROPERTY MODIFIED TO UPPERCASE OF OLD KEY
    interest: 100
};
```

then proceed with your code as it.

[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) [indexeddb](/questions/tagged/indexeddb) [html5](/questions/tagged/html5)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is a sensible solution however for a data set of couple of thousand rows this would be duplicating every entry... I was playing with recursion and using one bound with toUpperCase and one with toLowerCase but still nothing concrete..

Comment: In your code, when you specified a keyRange, you were querying single row or multiple rows?

Comment: Multiple rows. What I'm trying to do, is when you press a letter e.g. 'F', the autocomplete box return FRESH FURIT, fragances, fReSh Salad... So by pressing 'F' the search on idexeddb returns all products irrelevant what the product name starts with, i.e. lowercase 'f' or uppercase 'F'... I know in SQL it would be a lot easier but I thought to give indexeddb a go as it seems to be a way local storage is going forward...

Comment: what if you set lower bound to `term.toUpperCase()` and set upper bound to `term.toLowerCase() + 'z'`

Comment: Yes, this is good. I think this is the best we can do till spesification updates and then browser vendors respond.

Answer (score 4):

[Dexie.js](https://github.com/dfahlander/Dexie.js) does great job at case insensitive search without additional index.

Comment: Do you know the devs behind this? New to me thanks for sharing.

Comment: No, but looks awesome library.

Comment: Here is a great article from the author. It seems like a really great library with great performance. https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/06/breaking-the-borders-of-indexeddb/

Answer (score 1):

The reason you see what you see is that IndexedDB cursors are [lexicographically sorted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

Under this paradigm, a > A, unlike [alphabetical sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetical_order) which sounds more like what you're looking for.

To achieve alphabetical sorting you'd have to cursor through all records in your lexicographical sort (until you get null as `event.target.result` in your `onsuccess`), adding the results to a shared global and then, on completion of the lexicographical sort, return an alphabetical sort of your shared global.

Comment: Thanx for that. Still think there are more real world cases where alphabetical cursors would be useful rather than lexicographically but that's they way it is...

Comment: Totally agree. The spec is young enough that maybe it will happen.